# Facebook recommend button, not popping up the dialog box

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

The Facebook recommend button generator gave me a button for my website but it does not work as it works in the demo of Facebook, it is not popping up the dialog box also not fetching the right image.

I have set all the meta tags correctly and they are rending properly as well.

Here is one example post, 
http://makinsensebabe.com/ten-video-pictures-explaining-why-everyone-went-nutz-in-spain-last-week/

I have been searching on this issue from a few days now and not getting any suitable answer, not even fetching the right image every time after setting the meta tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) you're missing some of the meta tags needed:

`Admins And App ID Missing  fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.`

Comment: No use, even after giving the admin and app ID, it is still not opening the facebook dialog box in which i can give a comment with the post and its not all the time picking the og:image picture for the thumbnail .... Very strange error

Comment: Now the facebook debugger not giving any issue but the POP UP is still not there.

Comment: Are you sure it's the XFBML version of the like/recommend plugin you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your url's status on [Facebook Debug for your object](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://makinsensebabe.com/ten-video-pictures-explaining-why-everyone-went-nutz-in-spain-last-week/) - and start from there.

Comment: no the url is auto generated since its simply wordpress blog, what i dont get is why the pop up doesnt open when i am using the code facebook gave me

Comment: You've got to keep looking at the debugger - it's [full](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://makinsensebabe.com/ten-video-pictures-explaining-why-everyone-went-nutz-in-spain-last-week/) of errors! You've put an invalid app id - your website.com is not registered with the app. Which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, that clears a lot ... It is not picking the correct image.

Comment: What is still not clear though, is why the pop up box is not opening when I click recommend.